# Bin pandas DataFrame values to discrete categories using quantiles of whole dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to bin pandas DataFrame values to discrete category labels (e.g. 1,2,3 or a,b,c) according to the values quantile "position". My DataFrame is a matrix (36x28) and I would like to categorize them into 10 classes. What I tried was to find the quantiles by

```
kor_2005_values = kor_2005.values.flatten()
kor_2005_quantiles = np.nanquantile(kor_2005_values,[0,.1,.2,.3,.4,.5,.6,.7,.8,.9,1])
```

and than bin/replace the values between the quantiles (e.g. between 0 and 0.1 by label "1" and 0.1 and 0.2 by 2) by

```
test = pd.cut(kor_2005, bins = kor_2005_quantiles, labels=['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10'])
```

which gives the error `ValueError: Input array must be 1 dimensional`. That is why I tried

```
test = pd.qcut(kor_2005_values, [0,.1,.2,.3,.4,.5,.6,.7,.8,.9,1], labels=['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10'])
```

which resulted in the error message `ValueError: Bin edges must be unique`.

Does someone know how to fix this or even better know a simpler option to replace/bin pandas DataFrame data independent from pandas rows/columns?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You are getting `ValueError: Bin edges must be unique` error because some of the quantiles are not unique - ie, you have quantiles of something like `[0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9., 9.]` (notice the two 9s)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. Yes, thats correct. I do have duplicate which needs to be taken into account. I cannot just drop them because I need these "duplicates", better their "category",  for further processing.

Comment: try using `pd.cut(kor_2005_values, kor_2005_quantiles, labels=np.arange(10)+1)`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Unfortunately it gives me the same error message as before: ```Bin edges must be unique```.